# .NET Role Based Access with Resources - best practice

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a .NET MVC application, and currently using only Role Based Access Control. I am wrapping my controllers endpoints with `[Authorize(Roles="Provider")]` for example. 
Now, I want to add the add permissions on resources as well, e.g. not only saying if a user can edit a document, but also to define which documents it can edit. 
So I want it to look something like -
`[Authorize(Roles="Provider")]
[Authorize("CanEditObject1")]`

What is the best practice for doing so? What type of authorization is required here? Perhaps I need to mix some (Role Based Access + Policy Based Access)? Do I need to change my whole Authentication method or just add on top of it?

Answer (score -1):

You will want to look into Policies. I too got schooled on this pretty fast when I tried submitting a PR for authorization tag helpers and never got back to it. In short define policies at your composition root and check those with Authorize attributes.

Row level access may require additional checking however unless you can establish membership levels.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the authorization at the controller level is read-only, a more restrictive "Edit" role could be enforced at the controller's edit methods by using an authorization attribute on the edit methods. I would also conditionally hide links to edit methods in the view from end users without that role. Another option is to leverage claims that the authenticated user has to discriminate their access to certain resources.